# Creating second sequence based on argument; Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

I have the following question. I have generated the following RowNumber column by usage of the rownumber() function and the over(paritation by clause. The counting starts with '1'  every time a new Number is listed:

| SEQ_NO | Number | RowNumber | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | PRD101 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD101 | 2 | 2 |
| 130 | PRD101 | 3 | 3 |
| 140 | PRD101 | 4 | 4 |
| 150 | PRD101 | 5 | 1 |
| 160 | PRD101 | 6 | 2 |
| 110 | PRD102 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD102 | 2 | 2 |
| 130 | PRD102 | 3 | 2 |
| 140 | PRD102 | 4 | 1 |
| 110 | PRD103 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD103 | 2 | 1 |

The query is kind of like this:

```
select seq_no, part_no, row_number() over(partition by part_no order by seq_no) as RowNumber, level 
from table1
```

The point is that I would like to create a second sequence which does not fill any value in for rows where levels > 2
The second sequence is also paritated by the part_no

The table would result like:

| SEQ_NO | Number | RowNumber | SecondRowNumber | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | PRD101 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD101 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 130 | PRD101 | 3 |  | 3 |
| 140 | PRD101 | 4 |  | 4 |
| 150 | PRD101 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 160 | PRD101 | 6 | 4 | 2 |
| 110 | PRD102 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD102 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 130 | PRD102 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 140 | PRD102 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 110 | PRD103 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD103 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a CTE with the wanted second row numbers and join it

```
WITH CTE as (
  select "SEQ_NO", "PART_NO"
  , row_number() over(partition by "PART_NO" order by "SEQ_NO") as RowNumber, "LEVEL"  
from table1
  WHERE "LEVEL"  <= 2
  )
select table1."SEQ_NO", table1."PART_NO"
  , row_number() over(partition by table1."PART_NO" order by table1."SEQ_NO") as RowNumber_
  , CTE.RowNumber as secondRowNumber
  , table1."LEVEL" 
from table1 LEFT JOIN CTE ON table1."SEQ_NO"  = CTE."SEQ_NO"  AND table1."PART_NO" = CTE."PART_NO"
```

| SEQ_NO | PART_NO | ROWNUMBER_ | SECONDROWNUMBER | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | PRD101 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD101 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 130 | PRD101 | 3 | *null* | 3 |
| 140 | PRD101 | 4 | *null* | 4 |
| 150 | PRD101 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 160 | PRD101 | 6 | 4 | 2 |
| 110 | PRD102 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD102 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 130 | PRD102 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 140 | PRD102 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 110 | PRD103 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 120 | PRD103 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wxDzU6vE)